# How can i show the value before the "." sign?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm creating a currency application but some of values are like "194.23564" or "1187.7594" so i want to show the user before the "." sign values. How can i make this with Kotlin ?

Comment: If they are `float` or `double` you can simply use `.toInt()` and it will be rounded down and drop all values after decimal.

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.math/truncate.html

Comment: @Pawel thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for data type conversion before the extraction of the integer part. 
You can use [`substringBefore()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/substring-before.html):

```
val number = "194.23564"
val intPart = number.substringBefore(".")
```

If you want the result as an integer number you can use now `toIntOrNull()`, instead of `toInt()`, so to avoid an exception in case the initial string has no integer part (like `".015"`):

```
val intPart = number.substringBefore(".").toIntOrNull()
```

Answer (score 1):

Other than suggested, I would **not convert to Float**. This is susceptible to rounding errors and may **not** return the value before the decimal point.

Example:

```
val num = "0.99999999"
println(num.toFloat().toInt())  // gives 1
```

Instead, split the string at the decimal point:

```
val num = "0.99999999"
val split = num.split('.')
println(split[0])  // gives 0
```

A nice side effect of this implementation is that it even works for integral numbers without a decimal point. If you need the result as an `Int`, simply call `split[0].toInt()`.

Answer (score -1):

There is no need to use float in this case. If you want to get the value before ".", you need to use int instead of float. When you use float you will get value in points, but when you use int, you will get the value before ","